# C: Using serialized data as type

Tags: c, design-patterns, serialization

So I've run into an interesting design pattern and I wanted to know if you guys had an opinion on it.

Basically, the design is passing everything around as a pre-serialized type. There is no "types" for the returns, for example. It is passed as a simple uint8_t*. There is a defined header that "tells" you what is in the buffer, how big it is, what the version of the buffer is, ect. I call it "pre-serialized" because it forces flattening of all structures.

The pros:

1. You can easily write it (or even a set of it) to what ever you want. Files, IO, whatever.
2. Can store arbitrary data.

The Cons: IMHO:

1. No type safety is going to be a nightmare
2. The programmer has to parse the code. Even if there is an enumerated type, the user would have to know what that type means. Even if there are functions to parse the type, the programmer has to know that is the function to call.
3. Version hell: changing code will cause a ripple effect of errors. Because everywhere is parsing it differently, you have no idea where the code works or where it is broken.
4. It is viral: because it is flat, you can't "insert" the header on the end of outside data. You could wrap the call if you copy your "data", but this could cause an unnecessary copy that would be SLOW. So either your code is slower than it needs to be, or you conform to this data structure.
5. It isn't human readable OR debug-able.

Have you seen this design pattern before? Is there a name for this design pattern? Things I missed?

Comment: You normally only do this kind of thing for well-delineated external APIs, e.g. between distinct "modules" (programs/libraries/streams/whatever). It doesn't make sense to apply serialization internally, within a module.

Comment: @PaulR It seems to me the purpose where was to make it stupidly easyto move the data between different modules, though the delineation isn't that well defined....It would seem to me that if you don't have a shared way to parse the data type, then this creates more problems than it solves...

Comment: Well the most common scenario is when you have data that needs to be streamed somehow, e.g. binary file formats, network data, etc. I can't see any benefit within modules, at least for modules that have the same ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Honza said this would be normal in Legacy **Cobol/PL1** (was there a **Cobol/PL1** conversion or interface to COBOL programs ???).

In **COBOL** this *design pattern* would make **sense**, not sure about **C** though (one of the binary serialization packages or JSON etc might be more sensible).

In **Cobol**, you would have a **Cobol copybook** which all programs would use and could **edit** the data using the **Cobol Copybook** (with something like file-aid or [Microfocus Data Editor](https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/sx20books/utdfet.htm)).

---

Why use this **"design pattern"** in Cobol:

- Regression testing of Modules; you can write  a driver module like

```
    Read Test-data-file
    while more-data
        Call Module
        write Result to output-file
        Read Test-data-file
    end

    You can then do a compare between Output from the 
    re-Change Program to the changed program.
```

- Testing - some times you can use a "production file" in testing
- A file provides trace or snapshot of what is going on, this can be very useful.
- Easy to reorganize Batch streams:

  - Split a programs up (and pass the data via file). There variety of reason for doing this including

    - program has gotten to big and is hard to maintain.
    - Sorting the data
    - Performance (use a file rather than hitting the DB multiple times)
    - new uses for extracted data

---

While your **cons** are valid for C, they will be less of an issue in Cobol.

The key to using this **"design pattern"** is being able to **edit/view/compare** the format. If you can not **edit/view/compare** a file, I do not see the point

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a name for this design pattern?

Well, **Legacy Code**? :) I have seen such design in 30 years old Cobol systems...

The pros you have stated are easily reachable also by using **XML format** (or JSON):

1. You can easily write it (or even a set of it) to what ever you want. Files, IO, whatever - most of all, **web services**!
2. Can store arbitrary data.

Furthermore, all your cons are eliminated.

The only pro I can see in your solution is **conciseness** - when every byte counts and you need to avoid any overhead as too expensive, then this is nice.

Added: **Cobol** has a feature to easily define the structure of such serialized data, see [PICTURE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_clause) clause. Reading the data is very easy then, you read them as variables. (Like if you have a binary data and define a *struct* in the C language and typecast the binary to the *struct*.)